# Does the Joker say he loves Harley Quinn?

Tags: dc, the-joker

*Does the Joker ever say, directly or indirectly, that he loves Harley Quinn?* I know people say that he doesn't and he just uses her, and on the other half their relationship is described as mad love, but does the Joker ever say anything to confirm feelings for Harley Quinn? (I'm not looking for a sign of affection, just him actually saying he loves her or has strong feelings for her)

[image]